# install magento on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami, amazon-ami

I want to install magento for production site on EC2 instance. I was looking at bitnami magento stack and I installed it. Can I use it for production and what are the things that must be changed?

Is there any AMI that is ready for production? Or else what is your recommendation for my case?

Regards,

Comment: I only used Bitnami for the LAMP stack to get it up quickly and then install Magento myself so 3rd party developers could work on an issue. The Magento side of things is best taken care of by the site owner, and as Jeevan points out below, best to build a good server instance yourself for live. Bitnami's advice for Magento upgrades to new versions when using their full Magento instance is to basically jack up the radiator cap and drive a new car under it, something that is intolerable for either a dev or live server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami instances are good for testing and development but I dont prefer to use it for production. Its better to configure your own magento stack using a base OS instance like ubuntu centos or amazon linux.

I dont suggest any of the third party instances for production.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to setup a stack with a base OS, I am most familiar with Ubuntu, should I go for it or you have another recommendation? Is there any guide to make sure I do this right?

Comment: Even I prefer ubuntu for all given reasons. I am running large number of ubuntu instance in production and its working seemlessly. There must be lot of guides to do it. Let me knw if you need more help